# Linking with GCC doesn't detect -fPIC flag

Tags: ld, fpic, multiboot

I am trying to link some files. Here is my command:

```
gcc -T linker.ld -o Stack\ Berry.bin -ffreestanding -O2 -nostlib kernel.o boot.o -fPIC -lgcc
```

How ever, I get this error:

```
/usr/bin/ld: boot.o: relocation R_X86_64_32 against `.multiboot' can not be used when making a PIE object; recompile with -fPIC
/usr/bin/ld: final link failed: Nonrepresentable section on output
```

I have included the `-fPIC` argument, have I just put it in the wrong place? I have tried putting the argument in where it compiles but no luck. I haven't been able to find any thing for the syntax for this flag. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing `-fPIC` to your *linkage* command. It is a *compiler* option,
because you need to *compile* your source code to Position Independent object files.

Remove it from this command and add it to your compilation commands.

(`-O2` is likewise a compiler, not linker, option.)